# Why does changing these registry keys not enable the screensaver?

Tags: windows-registry, group-policy, screensaver

I'm trying to set up a powershell script that enables some screensaver group policy settings, so I found the corresponding registry keys and set them:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ScreenSaveActive"="1"
"ScreenSaverIsSecure"="1"
"SCRNSAVE.EXE"="scrnsave.scr"
"ScreenSaveTimeOut"="300"
```

All the screensaver settings appear to be correct; the wait time is 5 minutes and "display logon screen" is checked, but the screensaver never actually activates. When the settings are changed in the group policy manager it works fine.

Comment: I think these settings belong in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`.